# When initializing googlePayClient after onActivityCreated it gives this error: LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, braintree, google-pay

I am upgrading the braintree SDK for google payment services in my recent project. For that purpose I need to initiate a **`BraintreeClient(this,token)`** which requires a token which is being fetched later after an API call for `clientToken` in `onActivityCreated()` and eventually after that need to initiate **`GooglePayClient(this,braintreeclient)`**. And when I run this code while initialization, the error pops up saying:

> **LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED**.

Below is the code for the issue:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            paymentOptions = it.getSerializable(KEY_PAYMENT_METHODS) as? ArrayList<String>?
        }
}




override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

presenter.getPaymentOptionsWithClientToken(paymentOptions)
}



override fun setupPaymentOptionsWithClientToken(paymentOptionsWithClientToken: Pair<List<String>, String>) {
    val availablePaymentMethods = paymentOptionsWithClientToken.first.toMutableList()
    clientToken = paymentOptionsWithClientToken.second

    initBrainTreeFragment()
  
}


private fun initBrainTreeFragment(): Boolean {
        if (clientToken.isEmpty().not()) {
            braintreeClient = BraintreeClient(activity!!, clientToken)
            googlePayClient = GooglePayClient(activity!!,braintreeClient)
            googlePayClient.setListener(this)
            // braintreeFragment = BraintreeFragment.newInstance(activity, clientToken) // Earlier implementation
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

I tried making `clientToken` to get initialized to a lateinit token variable and use that token in `onCreate()` method to initialize braintree since it gets initialized if I put a static token in the statement  `braintreeClient = BraintreeClient(activity!!, clientToken)` when written in `onCreate()` method but not when written after `onActivityCreated()`.

So I basically want to use `clientToken` in `onCreate()` method after the call for token in `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: `onActivityCreated()` should not be used because it is deprecated. `onCreate()` is rarely needed either, and it's called before `onActivityCreated()` anyway. Just use `onViewCreated()` for all your setup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tenfour04, I'm still getting the error saying                                                                                                     ..:          .        . when trying to initiate googlepayclient as well like  googlePayClient = GooglePayClient(this,,braintreeClient)

Comment: I would have to see the complete, latest version of your code to be able to speculate. But I know nothing of Braintree, so I might not be able to help much.

Answer (score -1):

In your native module java file, in respective method, start android fragment (UI less).

In fragment's onCreate, initialise braintree client and google pay client.